# Как увязать вместе EditText и базу данных во ФРАГМЕНТЕ

Tags: android, android-fragment

База данных в обычном состоянии добавляет новую строку. Но стоит мне добавить:

```
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText0);
xValues.put("TEXT0", String.valueOf(editText.getText()));
```

Программа останавливается. Ответьте пожалуйста кто знает в чем дело?

Вод код на всякий случай:

```
public class ZK_CreationFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.zk_fragment_creation, container, false);

    view.findViewById(R.id.button_creation).setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ContentValues xValues = new ContentValues();
    xValues.put("TEXT0", "ааа");
    xValues.put("IMAGE0", R.drawable.z);
    xValues.put("TEXT1", "ббб");
    xValues.put("IMAGE1", R.drawable.z);
    xValues.put("TEXT2", "ввв");
    xValues.put("IMAGE2", R.drawable.z);
    xValues.put("TEXT3", "ггг");
    xValues.put("IMAGE3", R.drawable.z);
    xValues.put("TEXT4", "ддд");
    xValues.put("IMAGE4", R.drawable.z);

    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText0);
    xValues.put("TEXT0", String.valueOf(editText.getText()));

    SQLiteOpenHelper marigoldDatabaseHelper = new ZA_MarigoldDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = marigoldDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert("MANICURE", null, xValues);
        db.close();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Сохранено",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "База данных недоступна",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```

Вот логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zhoukov.marigold, PID: 3099
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не останавливается, но падает. Коли так - в логах должна быть ошибка. Скорее всего у вас там что-то типа NPE, т.к. в поле ввода нет текста никакого.

Comment: ID ресурсов в базу нет смысла писать - они могут поменяться при следующей сборке и записанное в базу число будет просто бесполезным.

Comment: Наверное вы хотите в БД писать текст который вводите в поле ввода. В таком случае вам надо в момент когда там что-то есть брать из него текст примерно так: `editText.getText().toString()`

Comment: Поменяла String.valueOf(editText.getText()) на editText.getText().toString() получилось тоже самое... Или я не там смотрю...

Comment: `EditText editText = requireView().findViewById(R.id.editText0);`

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Мне помогло)))